# Unable to receive XMPP upstream messages

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, xmpp

App Server is connected to XMPP and can send messages to the client in one go. But the client sends upstream messages through `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(remotemsage)`, and the App Server cannot receive it.

upstream message：

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(new RemoteMessage.Builder(to)
     .setMessageId(messageId)
     .addData("message", "111")
     .build());
```

```
@Override
public void onMessageSent(@NonNull String msgId) {
     super.onMessageSent(msgId);
     Log.e("TAG", "onMessageSent: " + msgId);
}
```

The `onMessageSent()` Log will print.

- First, the App Server is running on a personal computer and cannot receive it;
- Secondly, the App Server is run on the Singapore server, the client device is connected to the VPN, and the uplink is sent, but it still cannot be received;

What should I do to let the App server receive the upstream message?